# Support v7 widget toolbar not show 3 dots menu in Android 5.1

Tags: android-support-library, android-toolbar

Android 5.1 doesn't show 3 dots menu. In the AndroidManifest I have that:
`<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`
I use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar so in my activity that extends ActionBarActivity put `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
I also modify  the parent theme but it doesn't work. How can I show 3 dots menu in Android 5.1?

My menu is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
      <item
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/1"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>


<item
    android:id="@+id/2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/2"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_3"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/3"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/4"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_4"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/4"
    android:visible="false"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/5"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_5"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:title="@string/5"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/6"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_6"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:title="@string/6"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/7"
    android:orderInCategory="6"
    android:title="@string/7"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/8"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_8"
    android:orderInCategory="7"
    android:title="@string/8"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/9"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_9"
    android:orderInCategory="8"
    android:title="@string/9"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/10"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_10"
    android:orderInCategory="9"
    android:title="@string/10"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/11"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_11"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:title="@string/11"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/12"
    android:orderInCategory="98"
    android:title="@string/12"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/13"
    android:orderInCategory="99"
    android:title="@string/13"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I see a normal menu but in android 5.1 I can't see the 3 dots menu, in other android versions I can see 3 dots menu

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
```